# Keep log file at 23:00 hrs

Tags: debug

I have a scheduled job running at 23:00 hrs, Is possible to keep a log file from that hour saved somewhere? So I can see the degubs and errors in the morning?

A lot of thanks, 
Reg

Answer (score 1):

In Setup-> Debug Logs You can find the tools you're searching for.

There you can set up debug logs for certain users & apex classes.

You can find more detailed information here

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5

This way you can track whatever you need inside a time frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate the logs for 2 hours starting at 23:00, then run a query to retrieve the logs that were fired after or at 23:00.

1. activate logs going to **Setup->Monitoring->Debug Logs**
2. query the logs fired after or at 23:00, use following query:

   SELECT Id, Application, Status, DurationMilliseconds, StartTime 
   FROM ApexLog 
   WHERE StartTime >= YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ ORDER BY StartTime

If the literal **YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ** is confusing, check the literal documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm).